# previous files adding in pull Request(github)

Tags: git, github

Here is the problem i am facing right now,i am checking out a completely new branch,adding only relevant files/file eg `git add <filename>` and pushing onto a new branch,but when creating a new PR(pull request) on github,i am seeing some other files other than the specific file being showing in files changed numbers.This is really frustrating as i am pushing only a single file to new branch and creating a PR with base and that specific branch.how can i solve this issue?One way of solving i guess is to remove cached files `git rm --cached <filename>` when pushing onto new branch,but my lead is really pissed off as this is consider "deleting files!"

Comment: Well do you recall adding other files?  How did you `git add` the files you actually want to appear in this pull request?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have shared details

Comment: I don't see right now where `git rm --cached` comes into play.  Tell us which files you added before you committed, and maybe we can figure out how those unexpected files ended up in your pull request.

Comment: my workflow is simple.lets suppose i have 2 files and both files should get pushed to 2 separate branches.1 file in my case is going to 1 branch,but when after checking out to branch and pushing new file,the 1st one is also  going to the branch and being ended up in PR

Comment: You seemed confused about how Git works, and without a diagram I can't see what you really did or what really happened.  Suffice it to say, I doubt that Git is broken, but rather you are responsible for what is happening now.